# How it happens that I can take a picture by voice on Samsung Galaxy s7?

Tags: camera, samsung-galaxy-s7, voice-recognition

On my Samsung Galaxy S7 I can start camera application and then if I say "take picture" (in Russian) it automatically presses shutter button.

Who does this? Camera application itself?

Where I can know full list of voice commands? Can I start video recording by voice?

Answer (score 1):

Each app  can define voice commands it supports. Then whichever voice assistant you use will  take care of matching your voice command to each app's intent. Eg see https://developers.google.com/voice-actions on how to register voice commands with the Google voice assistant.